# Using Silhouette Score to evaluate different clustering algorithm

Tags: clustering, model-selection, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to compare different clustering algorithms on a dataset and compare the model performance. Since the dataset is quite big (56 features), I applied PCA to reduce the number of features to just 3 features and then ran the clustering algorithms on the 3 PCAs, followed by creating silhouette plots on the three PCAs to check for the ideal number of clusters

I noticed that although the silhouette plot for BIRCH model with 4 clusters does not seem optimal since there are clusters with negative silhouette scores, the clusters seem good when plotting the principal components.

Here are the screenshots.

[image]

Here is the plots between the PCA's with 4 clusters

[image]

According to me, I think 4 clusters looks great. But the silhouette plot dhows that this is not the case and that 2 clusters is the ideal number of clusters.

My question is, is silhouette plot suitable for choosing number of clusters for BIRCH models, or any models other than Kmeans clustering?

Searching online, I noticed silhouette plots were only used for kmeans algorithm.

Comment: It's not true that Silhouette plots are only used for kmeans. In Kaufman and Rousseeuw's "Finding Groups in Data" (and many other places) they are used for Partitioning Around Medoids, and I've seen literature where they have been used with all kinds of other methods.

Comment: A standard way of using the Silhouette for comparing models is to look at the Average Silhouette Width rather than wondering whether plots look "nice" or not. What are the average values here?

Comment: "Since the dataset is quite big (56 features), I applied PCA to reduce the number of features to just 3 features." Apart from whether this is a good idea (very often it isn't - why throwing away information?), I don't find it clear whether *all* analyses were run on the 3 PCAs. Is it true that both the clusterings and the Silhouettes were computed on 3 PCAs, or did any of these the original features?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments. So, I applied PCA, then did clustering on the 3 PCAs, followed by computing the scores on the 3PCAs. For the average silhouette values, 4 clusters gave a score of approximately 0.5 and for 2 clusters, an average score of almost 0.39.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I pressed enter earlier before completing writing the answers, Now you will see that I have answered your questions.

Comment: So the Average Silhouette Width says in fact that 4 is better than 2, which is what your visual impression says as well - there may not be a problem. Surely it's not true that 2 is "ideal" according to the Silhouette plot. Having a few negative values doesn't mean that it's overall bad.

Comment: By the way, better write such informations in the question so that others see them immediately as well.

Comment: Thanks, just edited the question now.

Comment: 1) Silhouette clustering criterion (SCC) can be used along with any clustering method. 3) There exist more tnan one version of SCC. 4) To select the "best" number of clusters k by SCC, people usually don't inspect the Silhouette Width plots like that you show. They are plotting the line plot of mean SCC (plus st. deviation of it as error bars), the X axis being k (2, 3,...,15,say).